# Errors when playing some mp3 files in webview

Tags: android, audio, webview

My app contains a WebView. In the javascript I load an mp3 file and play it at specific moment.
There are plenty of pages like that, from different providers.
Until today, all of the content played nicely, including small, large [10MB+] mp3 files, m4a files etc.
Today I have stumbled upon content with mp3 files below 1MB which won't play at all.
I have looked at logcat and all relevant I have found was:

```
 03-22 17:49:09.812 262-779/? I/AudioFlinger: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST accepted: frameCount=256 mFrameCount=128
03-22 17:49:09.812 262-779/? E/AudioMixer: AudioMixer::getTrackName out of available tracks
03-22 17:49:09.812 262-779/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
03-22 17:49:09.812 262-779/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
03-22 17:49:09.812 15504-15625/com.App E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
03-22 17:49:09.813 15504-15625/com.App E/libOpenSLES: AudioTrack::initCheck status 4294967284
03-22 17:49:09.813 15504-15625/com.App W/libOpenSLES: Leaving Object::Realize (SL_RESULT_CONTENT_UNSUPPORTED)
```

I am not using 32 channels, the device I have tried that on has only a single app running and I have only tried a single mp3 file.

Is there anything I am missing?

Here's the info of the mp3 file:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to play those files was to encode them into something "more standard" like CBR 192kbps. After the re-encoding, all audio worked fine.